# Symfony and Doctrine: sluggable behaviour: field called "slug" is not created

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, slug

I have this model:

```
Usuario:
   actAs:
     Sluggable:
       unique: true
       fields:  [nombre_apellidos]
       canUpdate: true
   inheritance:
     extends: sfGuardUser
     type: simple
   columns:
     username:
       type: string(128)
       notnull: false
       unique: true
     nombre_apellidos: string(60)
     sexo: boolean
     fecha_nac: date
     provincia: string(60)
     localidad: string(255)
     #email_address: string(255)
     fotografia: string(255)
     avatar: string(255)
   relations:
     Usuario:
       local: user1_id
       foreign: user2_id
       refClass: AmigoUsuario
       equal: true
```

I expected the field called 'slug' was created after "build
doctrine:build --all", but no.

Why is a field called "slug" is not created?

Symfony 1.3

Comment: which version of Doctrine did you use ? as of 1.2 this should work, but I don't know symfony 1.3 enough

Comment: I was trying to create the slug field in a table (Usuario) that is not created if you use the simple inheritance. I replaced in the schema the inheritance type from 'simple' to 'concrete' and now the table Usuario is created with the slug field inside.

Answer (score 1):

I met same problem and fixed by setting unique to false. If the unique is not very important to you, it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Usuario:
   actAs:
     Sluggable:
       unique: true
       name: slug
       fields:  [nombre_apellidos]
       canUpdate: true
```

name should be by default 'slug', guess this won't help.

Answer (score 0):

If `Usario.class.php` contains a `getSlug()` method, then just remove it from there, and all will work.